# Loop over a column if a element of a list found do something in that row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel file with the following structure

```
Profile     Gene  Refseq
Panel1_yes   AAA   NA123
Panel1_yes   BBB   NA456
Pane_no      CCC   NA123
Panel1_yes   DDD   NA123
```

I want to iterate over Profile column and if value match a list of values, generate a new column that concatenate columns Gene and Refseq in a new book

```
Profile      New_column
Panel1_yes    AAA_NA123
Panel1_yes    BBB_NA456
Panel1_yes    DDD_NA123
```

Searching on tutorial I cant found how to ask excel to do something in the row that the value has matched with the element of my list.

```
Sub test()

Dim awb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim a_lastrow As Integer     'last row of column A
Dim b_lastrow As Integer     'last row of column B

    Set awb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = awb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws

        a_lastrow = .Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row
        b_lastrow = .Range("B100000").End(xlUp).Row

        For r = 1 To a_lastrow

            If .Range("A" & r).Value = "My_list" Then
                .Range("B" & r).Value = ...
             End If

        Next r

    End With

    MsgBox ("done")

End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like your `If` tests for the match.  Within that `If` you would create your new workbook and add a worksheet with the profile and concatenated values.  Also, declare your `last_row` variables as `Long`, not `Integer`.  `Integer` will return an error if `row>=2^15`, and gets converted to a `Long` internally by VBA anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that sets up both your source and the destination workbooks and shows you how to transfer the data between them. Plus some helpful tips below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub testme()
    FindValues "Panel1_yes"
End Sub

Sub FindValues(ByVal value As String)
    Dim srcWB As Workbook
    Dim srcWS As Worksheet
    Set srcWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set srcWS = srcWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim dstWB As Workbook
    Dim dstWS As Worksheet
    Set dstWB = ThisWorkbook   '--- change to the new workbook
    Set dstWS = dstWB.Sheets("Sheet2")
    
    '--- find the end of the data in the destination sheet
    Dim dstRow As Long
    With dstWS
        dstRow = .Cells(.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    
    With srcWS
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To lastRow
            If IsInMyList(.Cells(i, 1).value) Then
                dstRow = dstRow + 1
                dstWS.Cells(dstRow, 1).value = .Cells(i, 1).value
                dstWS.Cells(dstRow, 2).value = .Cells(i, 2).value & "_" & .Cells(i, 3).value
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub

Function IsInMyList(ByVal value As String) As Boolean
    Dim theList() As String
    theList = Split("Panel1,Panel1_yes,Panel2_yes", ",")
    
    Dim item As Variant
    For Each item In theList
        If item = value Then
            IsInMyList = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next item
    IsInMyList = False
End Function
```

Here are the good habits for your VBA code:

1. [Always use `Option Explicit`](https://riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/3554/always-use--option-explicit-)
2. Always be clear on what [worksheet or range is being referenced](https://riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/5110/qualifying-references)
3. Use intermediate variables (such as `lastRow`) to help yourself make your code more readable. Yes, it's a few extra lines of code. But in many instances it can make your code faster (if that's a concern), but you'll find readability  will always be a bigger help to you in the long run.

Good luck!

Comment: Many thanks for your advices and code! Could you explain me what the first Sub does?

Comment: @ManuelDominguez the design of the code follows a principal of [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). In your case it means that you have some code that you might be using the `FindValues` sub with different values to search, so it was created with a parameter `value` to be passed in. The first sub `testme` is just a simple way to check out the new code (because we don't know what your real code needs to do). Continuing the idea, searching for the value in a list in pulled into its own function `IsInMyList`. All much easier to read.