# Selecting specific column in a macro excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using the code (code show below) suggested by PeterT in [this public question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70803356/loop-over-a-column-if-a-element-of-a-list-found-do-something-in-that-row)

This macro works well if the data are in the first, second and third column like this  of the sheet like this:

[image]

But now I have a more large spreadsheet and I would like to do the same but having one column and the other not immediately adjacent like this.

[image]

What modification do I need to do in the code to be able to do this.

```
Option Explicit

Sub testme()
    FindValues "Profile"
End Sub

Sub FindValues(ByVal value As String)
    Dim srcWB As Workbook
    Dim srcWS As Worksheet
    Set srcWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set srcWS = srcWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim dstWB As Workbook
    Dim dstWS As Worksheet
    Set dstWB = ThisWorkbook   '--- change to the new workbook
    Set dstWS = dstWB.Sheets("Sheet2")
    
    '--- find the end of the data in the destination sheet
    Dim dstRow As Long
    With dstWS
        dstRow = .Cells(.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    
    With srcWS
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To lastRow
            If IsInMyList(.Cells(i, 1).value) Then
                dstRow = dstRow + 1
                dstWS.Cells(dstRow, 1).value = .Cells(i, 1).value
                dstWS.Cells(dstRow, 2).value = .Cells(i, 2).value & "_" & .Cells(i, 3).value
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub

Function IsInMyList(ByVal value As String) As Boolean
    Dim theList() As String
    theList = Split("Albinism and nystagmus 31-gene panel,TAAD 27-gene panel (R125),PCD 29-gene panel", ",")
    
    Dim item As Variant
    For Each item In theList
        If item = value Then
            IsInMyList = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next item
    IsInMyList = False
End Function
```

I have tried by changing the selection of the column where I think the code does that but I dont get non a error neither the desired results

```
For i = 1 To lastRow
            If IsInMyList(.Cells(i, 2).value) Then
                dstRow = dstRow + 1
                dstWS.Cells(dstRow, 2).value = .Cells(i, 2).value
                dstWS.Cells(dstRow, 4).value = .Cells(i, 4).value & "_" & .Cells(i, 7).value
```

Answer (score 1):

### Non-Adjacent Columns

- This is easily achieved by adding a string (`srcColsList`) containing the columns, writing the columns to an array (`srcCols`), and using the elements of the array as column 'identifiers', e.g. `srcCols(0)`.
- You are not using the parameter `Profile` passed to your sub, so I removed it.
- Modify the `A,F,D` to fit your needs.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub testme()
    FindValues
End Sub

Sub FindValues()
    
    Const srcColsList As String = "A,F,D" ' no spaces!
    Dim srcCols() As String: srcCols = Split(srcColsList, ",")
    
    Dim srcWB As Workbook: Set srcWB = ThisWorkbook
    Dim srcWS As Worksheet: Set srcWS = srcWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim dstWB As Workbook: Set dstWB = ThisWorkbook
    Dim dstWS As Worksheet: Set dstWS = dstWB.Sheets("Sheet2")
    
    '--- find the end of the data in the destination sheet
    Dim dstRow As Long
    With dstWS
        dstRow = .Cells(.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    
    With srcWS
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Cells.Rows.Count, srcCols(0)).End(xlUp).Row
        
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To lastRow
            If IsInMyList(.Cells(i, srcCols(0)).Value) Then
                dstRow = dstRow + 1
                dstWS.Cells(dstRow, 1).Value = .Cells(i, srcCols(0)).Value
                dstWS.Cells(dstRow, 2).Value = .Cells(i, srcCols(1)).Value _
                    & "_" & .Cells(i, srcCols(2)).Value
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub

Function IsInMyList(ByVal SearchString As String) As Boolean
    Const StringList As String _
        = "Albinism and nystagmus 31-gene panel," _
        & "TAAD 27-gene panel (R125)," _
        & "PCD 29-gene panel" ' no spaces!
    IsInMyList = IsNumeric(Application _
        .Match(SearchString, Split(StringList, ","), 0))
End Function
```