# Creating a list from a column that contains unique values

Tags: excel, vba

How can I create a list from a column that contains unique values?

I am developing a code that do in essence [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70803356/loop-over-a-column-if-a-element-of-a-list-found-do-something-in-that-row). I am in fact using the code shared by PeterT.

At the end of the script, there is the list `theList` . I have created a new sheet (called Generator) with a bottom and some indications to allow the user to put in the column A the elements their wish to add.

The line in the code of PeterT that does that is

```
 theList = Split("Panel1,Panel1_yes,Panel2_yes", ",")
```

What I am trying without luck is to introduce some modification in the code to take the values from column A (imagine user put in the column A

```
Panel9
Panel12
Panel13
```

so `theList`  should be now  `theList = Split("Panel1,Panel1_yes,Panel2_yes", ",")`

How can I do that

EDIT:

The full code I am using with the BigBen's suggestion (I haven't checked yet if this worked)

```
Option Explicit

Sub testme()
    FindValues "Panel1_yes"
End Sub

Sub FindValues(ByVal value As String)
    Dim srcWB As Workbook
    Dim srcWS As Worksheet
    Set srcWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set srcWS = srcWB.Sheets("Gene_list")
    
    Dim dstWB As Workbook
    Dim dstWS As Worksheet
    Set dstWB = ThisWorkbook   '--- change to the new workbook
    Set dstWS = dstWB.Sheets("Results")
    
    '--- find the end of the data in the destination sheet
    Dim dstRow As Long
    With dstWS
        dstRow = .Cells(.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    
    With srcWS
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To lastRow
            If IsInMyList(.Cells(i, 1).value) Then
                dstRow = dstRow + 1
                dstWS.Cells(dstRow, 1).value = .Cells(i, 1).value
                dstWS.Cells(dstRow, 2).value = .Cells(i, 2).value & "_" & .Cells(i, 3).value
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub

Function IsInMyList(ByVal value As String) As Boolean
    Dim theList() As String

'--- BigBen's suggestion 

    thelist = Split("A1:A10")
'--- Need to modify the previous line to 1) to select the Worksheet call Generator from A1  to the last cell that contains a value and check if this work as well as the thelist with the values in this code. Then, I will delete the following thelist
    theList = Split("Panel1,Panel1_yes,Panel2_yes", ",")
    
    Dim item As Variant
    For Each item In theList
        If item = value Then
            IsInMyList = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next item
    IsInMyList = False
End Function
```

Comment: `Split` creates an array. So maybe you just need to create an array from those values, which is [very easy](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx).

Comment: Do you mean that you want to write the unique values from a column, that has duplicates, to the `theList` array?

Comment: THere is not duplicate values.

Comment: Could you share the code you've got, the one with the part where the user inputs e.g. `A`?

Comment: I havent done that yet but I am going to edit my question adding what I think I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

### Lookup Values From a List

```vb
Option Explicit

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      In one worksheet ('sName'), searches for values in a column
'               ('slfCellAddress'), existing in another worksheet's ('lName')
'               column ('lfCellAddress'), and writes them to one column
'               ('dlfCellAddress'), and writes the concatenated ('svDelimiter')
'               values of other columns ('svColsList') to another column
'               ('dvCol'), of another worksheet ('dName').
' Calls:        RefColumn,GetRange,DictColumn,ExistsInDictionary.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub LookupValues()
    Const ProcName As String = "LookupValues"
    
    Dim IsSuccess As Boolean
    
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    ' Lookup
    Const lName As String = "Sheet3"
    Const lfCellAddress As String = "A2" ' 2.) is found in these...
    ' Source Lookup
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const slfCellAddress As String = "A2" ' 1.) if this..., 3. write this...
    Const svColsList As String = "B,C" ' 5.) and concatenate these...
    Const svDelimiter As String = "_" ' 6.) using this...
    Const sfRow As Long = 2
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dlfCellAddress As String = "A2" ' 4. to a new row in this...
    Const dvCol As String = "B" ' 7. in the same row of this.
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Write the Lookup ('l') values to a dictionary ('lDict').
    Dim lws As Worksheet: Set lws = wb.Worksheets(lName)
    Dim lrg As Range: Set lrg = RefColumn(lws.Range(lfCellAddress))
    Dim lData As Variant: lData = GetRange(lrg)
    Dim lDict As Object: Set lDict = DictColumn(lData)
    If lDict Is Nothing Then Err.Raise 91, , "No data in the dictionary."
        
    ' Write the Source Lookup ('sl') value to an array ('slData').
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim slrg As Range: Set slrg = RefColumn(sws.Range(slfCellAddress))
    Dim slData As Variant: slData = GetRange(slrg)
    
    ' Write the Source Value ('sv') values to an array of arrays ('svData').
    Dim svCols() As String: svCols = Split(svColsList, ",")
    Dim svUpper As Long: svUpper = UBound(svCols)
    Dim svData As Variant: ReDim svData(0 To svUpper)
    Dim sv As Long
    For sv = 0 To svUpper
        svData(sv) = GetRange(slrg.EntireRow.Columns(svCols(sv)))
    Next sv
    Dim svLen As Long: svLen = Len(svDelimiter)
    
    Dim sr As Long
    Dim dr As Long
    Dim svString As String
    
    ' Write results to the same arrays.
    For sr = 1 To UBound(slData, 1)
        If ExistsInDictionary(lDict, slData(sr, 1)) Then
            ' Write lookup.
            dr = dr + 1
            slData(dr, 1) = slData(sr, 1)
            ' Write value (concatenate values) to a string ('svString').
            svString = vbNullString
            For sv = 0 To svUpper
                svString = svString & svData(sv)(sr, 1) & svDelimiter
            Next sv
            svString = Left(svString, Len(svString) - svLen)
            svData(1)(dr, 1) = svString
        End If
    Next sr
    Set lDict = Nothing
        
    ' Referenece the destination first cell ('dfCell').
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dlfCell As Range
    With dws.Range(dlfCellAddress)
        Set dlfCell = .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
           .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If dlfCell Is Nothing Then
            Set dlfCell = .Cells
        Else
            Set dlfCell = dlfCell.Offset(1)
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Write Lookup and Value data to the (one-column) ranges.
    Dim dlrg As Range: Set dlrg = dlfCell.Resize(dr) ' dr - destination last row
    dlrg.Value = slData
    Dim dvrg As Range: Set dvrg = dlrg.EntireRow.Columns(dvCol)
    dvrg.Value = svData(1)
        
    IsSuccess = True
        
ProcExit:
    If IsSuccess Then
        MsgBox "Values updated.", vbInformation, ProcName
    Else
        MsgBox "Something went wrong.", vbCritical, ProcName
    End If
    
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to the one-column range ('crg') whose first
'               cell is defined by the first cell of the range ('FirstCell')
'               and whose last cell is the bottom-most non-empty cell
'               of the first cell's worksheet column.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefColumn( _
    ByVal FirstCell As Range) _
As Range
    Const ProcName As String = "RefColumn"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    With FirstCell.Cells(1)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        Set RefColumn = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the values of a range ('rg') in a 2D one-based array.
' Remarks:      If ˙rg` refers to a multi-range, only its first area
'               is considered.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetRange( _
    ByVal rg As Range) _
As Variant
    Const ProcName As String = "GetRange"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    If rg.Rows.Count + rg.Columns.Count = 2 Then ' one cell
        Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
        GetRange = Data
    Else ' multiple cells
        GetRange = rg.Value
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the unique values from a column ('ColumnIndex')
'               of a 2D array ('Data') in the keys of a dictionary.
' Remarks:      Error values and blanks are excluded.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function DictColumn( _
    ByVal Data As Variant, _
    Optional ByVal ColumnIndex As Variant) _
As Object
    Const ProcName As String = "DictColumn"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' case-insensitive
    
    Dim c As Long
    
    If IsMissing(ColumnIndex) Then
       c = LBound(Data, 2) ' use first column index
    Else
       c = CLng(ColumnIndex)
    End If
    
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = LBound(Data, 1) To UBound(Data, 1)
        Key = Data(r, c)
        If Not IsError(Key) Then ' exclude error values
            If Len(CStr(Key)) > 0 Then ' exclude blanks
                dict(Key) = Empty
            End If
        End If
    Next r
   
    If dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Function ' only error values and blanks
    
    Set DictColumn = dict

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns a boolean indicating whether a value ('SearchValue')
'               exists in the keys of an existing ('ByRef') dictionary ('dict').
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function ExistsInDictionary( _
    ByRef dict As Object, _
    ByVal SearchValue As Variant) _
As Boolean
    Const ProcName As String = "DictColumn"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    If dict.Exists(SearchValue) Then ExistsInDictionary = True

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

### EDIT

- This solution asks the user to input a column string.

```vb
Sub LookupColumnValuesTEST()
    
    Const aibPrompt As String = "Input the column string"
    Const aibTitle As String = "Lookup Column Values"
    Const aibDefault As String = "A"
    
    Dim aib As Variant
    
    aib = Application.InputBox(aibPrompt, aibTitle, aibDefault, , , , , 2)
    If aib = False Then
        MsgBox "You canceled.", vbExclamation, aibTitle
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    LookupColumnValues aib
    
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      In one worksheet ('sName'), searches for values in a column
'               ('slfCellAddress'), existing in another worksheet's ('lName')
'               column ('lfCellAddress'), and writes them to one column
'               ('dlfCellAddress'), and writes the concatenated ('svDelimiter')
'               values of other columns ('svColsList') to another column
'               ('dvCol'), of another worksheet ('dName').
' Calls:        RefColumn,GetRange,DictColumn,ExistsInDictionary.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub LookupColumnValues( _
        ByVal LookupColumn As String)
    Const ProcName As String = "LookupColumnValues"
    
    Dim IsSuccess As Boolean
    
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    ' Lookup
    Const lName As String = "Generator"
    Const lfRow As Long = 2 ' 2.) is found in the lookup column...
    ' Source Lookup
    Const sName As String = "Gene_list"
    Const slfCellAddress As String = "A2" ' 1.) if this..., 3. write this...
    Const svColsList As String = "B,C" ' 5.) and concatenate these...
    Const svDelimiter As String = "_" ' 6.) using this...
    Const sfRow As Long = 2
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Results"
    Const dlfCellAddress As String = "A2" ' 4. to a new row in this...
    Const dvCol As String = "B" ' 7. in the same row of this.
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Write the Lookup ('l') values to a dictionary ('lDict').
    Dim lws As Worksheet: Set lws = wb.Worksheets(lName)
    Dim lrg As Range: Set lrg = RefColumn(lws.Cells(lfRow, LookupColumn))
    Dim lData As Variant: lData = GetRange(lrg)
    Dim lDict As Object: Set lDict = DictColumn(lData)
    If lDict Is Nothing Then Err.Raise 91, , "No data in the dictionary."
        
    ' Write the Source Lookup ('sl') values to an array ('slData').
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim slrg As Range: Set slrg = RefColumn(sws.Range(slfCellAddress))
    Dim slData As Variant: slData = GetRange(slrg)
    
    ' Write the Source Value ('sv') values to an array of arrays ('svData').
    Dim svCols() As String: svCols = Split(svColsList, ",")
    Dim svUpper As Long: svUpper = UBound(svCols)
    Dim svData As Variant: ReDim svData(0 To svUpper)
    Dim sv As Long
    For sv = 0 To svUpper
        svData(sv) = GetRange(slrg.EntireRow.Columns(svCols(sv)))
    Next sv
    Dim svLen As Long: svLen = Len(svDelimiter)
    
    Dim sr As Long
    Dim dr As Long
    Dim svString As String
    
    ' Write results to the same arrays.
    For sr = 1 To UBound(slData, 1)
        If ExistsInDictionary(lDict, slData(sr, 1)) Then
            ' Write lookup.
            dr = dr + 1
            slData(dr, 1) = slData(sr, 1)
            ' Write value (concatenate values) to a string ('svString').
            svString = vbNullString
            For sv = 0 To svUpper
                svString = svString & svData(sv)(sr, 1) & svDelimiter
            Next sv
            svString = Left(svString, Len(svString) - svLen)
            svData(1)(dr, 1) = svString
        End If
    Next sr
    Set lDict = Nothing
        
    ' Referenece the destination first cell ('dfCell').
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dlfCell As Range
    With dws.Range(dlfCellAddress)
        Set dlfCell = .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
           .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If dlfCell Is Nothing Then
            Set dlfCell = .Cells
        Else
            Set dlfCell = dlfCell.Offset(1)
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Write Lookup and Value data to the (one-column) ranges.
    Dim dlrg As Range: Set dlrg = dlfCell.Resize(dr) ' dr - destination last row
    dlrg.Value = slData
    Dim dvrg As Range: Set dvrg = dlrg.EntireRow.Columns(dvCol)
    dvrg.Value = svData(1)
        
    IsSuccess = True
        
ProcExit:
    If IsSuccess Then
        MsgBox "Values updated.", vbInformation, ProcName
    Else
        MsgBox "Something went wrong.", vbCritical, ProcName
    End If
    
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```